# Serverless Framework: how to deploy with CloudFormation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am new to the serverless framework. Well, at least to the latest version, which depends heavily on CloudFormation.

I installed the framework globally on my computer using:

```
npm install -g serverless
```

I then created a service using:

```
serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path myService
```

Finally, I ran:

```
serverless deploy
```

Everything seems to deploy normally, it shows no error in the terminal.
I can see the CloudFormation files in a newly created, dedicated S3 bucket.

However, I cannot find the default `hello` Lambda function in the AWS Lambda console.

**What am I missing? Are the CloudFormation files not supposed to create Lambda functions upon deployment?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The reason the default `hello` Lambda function is not listed in the AWS Lambda console is because your Lambda function was uploaded to the default region (us-east-1), while the Lambda console displays the functions of another region.

To set the correct region for your functions, you can use the region field of the `serverless.yml` file.

**Make sure the region property is directly under the provider section**. With 2/4 spaces indent. Like this:

```
provider:
    region: eu-west-1
```

Alternatively, you can specify the region at deployment time, like so:

```
sls deploy --region eu-west-1
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use 4 spaces for identation. I use only 2 spaces and it works fine. What the YAML specification requires is consistency.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to place the region directly under the provider. You may set other properties between them.

Comment: @Zanon with directly under i mean under the provider. Somewhere. It is easy to place it outside the provider scope. And with 4 spaces I again try to remove the doubt that region is indented in the provider scope.

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I had made a super silly mistake:

```
I did not properly set the AWS region
```

So, I was looking for a lambda function in the wrong region: of course it could not be found!

> Before deploying, one must make sure to set the correct region

UPDATE Well actually, I had set the region in `serverless.yml` by providing:

```
region: eu-west-1
```

However, for some reason the default region was not overwritten, and the function was deployed to the wrong region. Odd, that.

Anyway, one easy way around this issue is to provide the region at deployment time:

```
sls deploy --region eu-west-1
```

Comment: What version of serverless are you using? Where in the serverless.yml file did you put region? It works for me with the region in serverless.yml.

Comment: @doorstuck: serverless version is 1.5.0; I uncommented the region field in the serverless.yml, just below '#you can overwrite defaults here'

Comment: Okay. Just make sure it is directly under the provider section. With 4 spaces indent. Then I am sure it will work.

Comment: @doorstuck you nailed it, it now works! I was not aware of the need to properly indent the region field relative to the provider section, I should have bothered to look into yml files. You deserve some rep, please provide an answer